# How to insert an image under the name references

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I want to insert a picture after the references title. For example:

[image]

The result I would like would be this:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions for solving this problem? I would like them to use the codes as shown below. I am using a documentclass of type "Abntex2".

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

%%% CITE        
\usepackage[alf,abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-etal-cite=3]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}


template test:
\cite{lamport1994latex}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bib name test}
\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't quite tell by the two lines of code, but it looks suspiciously like you are not actually using `biblatex` (as your TeX suggests), but classical BibTeX instead. In that case a solution will be completely different. Since you got two `biblatex`-based answers already, I suggest you ask a **new question** (with appropriate tagging) and a full MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) instead of a code snippet. (See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7678/35864)

Comment: @moewe, or we could turn the question into a generic one and offer answers that suit both biblatex and bibtex. As it stands now, the edit has likely made both answers wrong.

Comment: @DavidPurton My preferred way of action would have been to roll back the edit, edit this question to make clearer that it is about `biblatex` and then ask a new question about BibTeX. But I guess a combined question works as well. The trouble with BibTeX/`thebibliography` is that there the solution may possibly depend on the document class (or another package that redefines `thebibliography`), so even there a generic question is tricky.

Comment: moewe,  David Purton: I put more details on my difficulty. I hope someone can help me. Thanks !!!

Comment: This shows why you *must* always give a complete minimal example when you ask a question. Without a proper example, we just waste time giving solutions to a question that keeps changing.

Comment: **Please ask a new question with the new MWE** (and roll back this question to its initial `biblatex` state). See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7678/35864. The edits have completely changed the question (from `biblatex`, to generic BibTeX, to specialised BibTeX) and have completely invalidated the existing answers as well. That is one of the reasons why we always recommend people add a minimal example document to their questions from the start. Even supposedly simple questions can have very different answer depending on your setup.

Comment: @moewe is right. (I should have listened to him to start with and not modified my answer.) If you roll back the question, I'll roll back my answer to it's initial state. You should then accept one of the answers and we'll look at your new question.

Answer (score 5):

## A Classical BibTeX solution

You can patch `\thebibliography` to insert the image after the heading and before the list of references starts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\list}
  {\begin{center}
     \includegraphics{example-image}
   \end{center}
   \list}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\LaTeX{} \cite{companion} is a set of macros built atop \TeX{}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\end{document}
```

### Classical BibTeX output

[image: BibTeX output]

---

## A BibLaTeX solution

You can separate out the heading from the list of references and then put the image in between:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX{} \cite{companion} is a set of macros built atop \TeX{}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}.

\printbibheading

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\end{center}

\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

### BibLaTeX output

[image: BibLaTeX Output]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `prenote` argument to `\printbibliography`. Simply define the content you want to typeset between the heading and the bibliography with `\defbibnote`.

MWE adapted from [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524169/35864)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\defbibnote{addimage}{%
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
  \end{center}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX{} \cite{companion} is a set of macros built atop \TeX{}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}.

\printbibliography[prenote=addimage]
\end{document}
```

[image: "References" heading//Picture//Bibliography items]

Comment: Oh, nice! `biblatex` has endless options.